# How to get the date from the latest file in the S3 bucket using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

I got the requirement that in the PySpark, I need to get the latest date from the files in the s3.

How to get the date using Pyspark code?

The s3 files path, examples:

```
"s3://bucketname/folderpath/2021/10/10/file.parquet, s3://bucketname/folderpath/2021/10/08/file.parquet, s3://bucketname/folderpath/2021/10/05/file.parquet, s3://bucketname/folderpath/2021/10/02/file.parquet"
```

**Output**: Get the latest file date path from S3 and pick the date and assign to variable from the path.

**Example**:

- latest path: `s3://bucketname/folderpath/2021/10/10/file.parquet`
- Date variable: `date = 20211010`

Comment: Where are you running Spark? Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

```
file_paths = sc\
               .wholeTextFiles("s3://bucketname/folderpath/*/*/*/*.parquet")\
               .map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

most_recent_file = max(file_paths)

Date_variable = most_recent_file.split("/")[4] + \
                most_recent_file.split("/")[5] + \
                most_recent_file.split("/")[6]

print(Date_variable)

Out: '20211010'
```